# Make Python Zelle graphics tic tac toe play until one player gets 10 points

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I want the computer playing with the player with until one of them scores 10 points:

```
from graphics import *
board=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]#as bourd
window=GraphWin("Tic Tac Toe",700,700)
L0=Line(Point(250,50),Point(250,650)).draw(window)
L1=Line(Point(450,50),Point(450,650)).draw(window)
L2=Line(Point(50,250),Point(650,250))
L2.draw(window)
L3=Line(Point(50,450),Point(650,450))
L3.draw(window)
xTurn=True
num=0
while num<9:
    b=window.getMouse()
    pa,pb=int((b.x-50)/200)+1,int((b.y-50)/200)+1
    if board[pb-1][pa-1]==0:
        num+=1
        if xTurn:
            tex="X"
            xTurn=False
        else:
            tex="O"
            xTurn=True
        h=Text(Point(pa*150+50*(pa-1),pb*150+50*(pb-1)),tex).draw(window)
        h.setSize(36)
        if xTurn:
            h.setFill("blue")
            board[pb-1][pa-1]=1
        else:
            h.setFill("red")
            board[pb-1][pa-1]=2
    if num>4:
         if (board[0][0]==1 and board[0][1]==1 and board[0][2]==1) or(board[1][0]==1 and board[1][1]==1 and board[1][2]==1) or(board[2][0]==1 and board[2][1]==1 and board[2][2]==1):
                 print(" O is winner")
                 break
         elif (board[0][0]==2 and board[0][1]==2 and board[0][2]==2) or(board[1][0]==2 and board[1][1]==2 and board[1][2]==2) or (board[2][0]==2 and board[2][1]==2 and board[2][2]==2):
                 print(" X is winner")
                 break

         elif (board[0][0]==2 and board[1][0]==2 and board[2][0]==2) or(board[0][1]==2 and board[1][1]==2 and board[2][1]==2) or (board[0][2]==2 and board[1][2]==2 and board[2][2]==2):
                 print(" X is winner")
                 break
         elif (board[0][0]==1 and board[1][0]==1 and board[2][0]==1) or(board[0][1]==1 and board[1][1]==1 and board[2][1]==1) or (board[0][2]==1 and board[1][2]==1 and board[2][2]==1):
                 print(" O is winner")
                 break
         elif (board[0][0]==1 and board[1][1]==1 and board[2][2]==1) or(board[0][2]==1 and board[1][1]==1 and board[2][0]==1):
                 print(" O is winner")
                 break
         elif (board[0][0]==2 and board[1][1]==2 and board[2][2]==2) or(board[0][2]==2 and board[1][1]==2 and board[2][0]==2):
                 print(" X is winner")
                 break         
if num>=9:
    print("There is no winner!")
```

Comment: Can you try to format your code a little better? It's difficult to read as is. Also, what is your question? What's wrong with the code you have? What is the expected behavior and what is happening instead?

Comment: If you're going to ask questions (and/or answer them) here, I suggest you read [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and [edit] your question to fix it there — _not_ post it as tough it was an answer.

Comment: i'm sorry . the code is correct just i want to play with computer until one of player get 10 point

Answer (score 0):

I took your program apart and put it back together again to streamline it and allow it to play ten games before quitting.  It prints the results of the ten games as it exits.  This isn't exactly what you are after, but I believe gives you the tools you need to do what you want:

```
from graphics import *
from time import sleep

PLAYERS = ['Draw', 'O', 'X']
DRAW = PLAYERS.index('Draw')

COLORS = ['black', 'blue', 'red']

EMPTY = 0

window = GraphWin("Tic Tac Toe", 700, 700)

Line(Point(250, 50), Point(250, 650)).draw(window)
Line(Point(450, 50), Point(450, 650)).draw(window)
Line(Point(50, 250), Point(650, 250)).draw(window)
Line(Point(50, 450), Point(650, 450)).draw(window)

turn = PLAYERS.index('X')
scores = [0] * len(PLAYERS)
tokens = []

while sum(scores) < 10:
    for token in tokens:
        token.undraw()

    board = [[EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY], [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY], [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY]]

    squares_played = 0

    while squares_played < 9:
        point = window.getMouse()
        x, y = int((point.x - 50) / 200), int((point.y - 50) / 200)

        if board[y][x] == EMPTY:
            squares_played += 1
            board[y][x] = turn
            text = PLAYERS[turn]

            token = Text(Point(200 * x + 150, 200 * y + 150), text)
            token.setSize(36)
            token.setFill(COLORS[turn])
            token.draw(window)

            tokens.append(token)

            turn = len(PLAYERS) - turn

        if squares_played > 4:
            if EMPTY != board[0][0] == board[0][1] == board[0][2]:
                print("{} is winner".format(PLAYERS[board[0][0]]))
                scores[turn] += 1
                break
            elif EMPTY != board[1][0] == board[1][1] == board[1][2]:
                print("{} is winner".format(PLAYERS[board[1][1]]))
                scores[turn] += 1
                break
            elif EMPTY != board[2][0] == board[2][1] == board[2][2]:
                print("{} is winner".format(PLAYERS[board[2][2]]))
                scores[turn] += 1
                break

            elif EMPTY != board[0][0] == board[1][0] == board[2][0]:
                print("{} is winner".format(PLAYERS[board[0][0]]))
                scores[turn] += 1
                break
            elif EMPTY != board[0][1] == board[1][1] == board[2][1]:
                print("{} is winner".format(PLAYERS[board[1][1]]))
                scores[turn] += 1
                break
            elif EMPTY != board[0][2] == board[1][2] == board[2][2]:
                print("{} is winner".format(PLAYERS[board[2][2]]))
                scores[turn] += 1
                break

            elif EMPTY != board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2]:
                print("{} is winner".format(PLAYERS[board[1][1]]))
                scores[turn] += 1
                break
            elif EMPTY != board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board[2][0]:
                print("{} is winner".format(PLAYERS[board[1][1]]))
                scores[turn] += 1
                break

    if squares_played >= 9:
        print("There is no winner!")
        scores[DRAW] += 1

    sleep(2)

for index, player in enumerate(PLAYERS):
    print("{}: {}".format(player, scores[index]))
```

My rework relies on some parallel arrays, which is better than *no* arrays, but should evolve to a real data structure.

Comment: thanks just my question how can pc play with the real player ?